# Running SQL agent job from SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to run SQL agent job from SSIS package and make sure the control comes back to SSIS after job completes and executes the next task in the package. 
Is this possible?

Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: Check out the `Execute Sql Server Agent Job Task` task .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137858.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two viable options. Create an Execute SQL Task and use sp_start_job, or use the Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task.

Comment: But does SSIS waits till completion of SQL job and executes next task in the control flow after SQL job  finishes?

Comment: @user5661489, no it doesn't. Jobs are executed independently of the thread that starts them, unless you implement some sort of waiting mechanism in your code.